# FFCalender + Xcode 6.0.1 + UICollectionView in iPad Air iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.0 , Month View gets scattered

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using [FFCalender](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar). In that MonthView gets scattered

In Simulator `iPad 2 8.0`, `iPad 2 7.0`, `iPad Retina 7.0` and `iPad Retina 8.0` its fine

[image]

In Simulator `iPad Air 8.0` `iPad Air 7.1` and its not fine

[image]

**EDIT** : iPad Air 7.1 has also same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such `not` `calculating` the `right` `size` of the `cells`.

#### In FFMonthCollectionView.m

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   .....................

   //comment sizeOfCells
   //CGSize sizeOfCells =  CGSizeMake((self.frame.size.width-6*SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL)/7,(self.frame.size.height-([dateFirstDayOfMonth numberOfWeekInMonthCount]-1)*SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL-SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL)/[dateFirstDayOfMonth numberOfWeekInMonthCount]);
   
  //Add these line
  CGSize sizeOfCells = CGSizeMake((self.frame.size.width-7*SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL)/7, (self.frame.size.height-([dateFirstDayOfMonth numberOfWeekInMonthCount]-1)*SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL-SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL)/[dateFirstDayOfMonth numberOfWeekInMonthCount]);

  ......................

}
```

Refer [Month Calendar: Uicollectionview Cells have the right size calculated](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar/commit/dac289f4aa7925617849ff025b164b786c1a6dbe)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the spacing between cells is off. This could be caused by either your UICollectionView's edgeInset value or its inter item spacing value.

For UICollectionViews you need to use one of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`methods.
Specifically the delegate method that defines the minimum inter item spacing.

If you check out the [FFMonthCollectionView.m](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar/blob/master/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFMonthCalendarView/FFMonthCollectionView/FFMonthCollectionView.m) file, you will see the method below:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL;
}
```

The constant value `SPACE_COLLECTIONVIEW_CELL` is defined in [FFConstants.h](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar/blob/master/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFConstants.h).
You can try to either toy with this value or maybe override the above method with values of your own.

**EDIT**

It could have to do with the new autolayout in Xcode6. I originally dismissed this as an answer because I assumed you weren't using the FFCalendar view controllers with your storyboard, but that's a silly assumption to make.
Since the iPad 2 and iPad Air have different dimensions, you may need to add layout rules (such as alignment or sizing constraints) for the different iPads.
I'm not familiar with FFCalendar but it looks like the last update was in June of 2014 so they may not have accounted for the new unified storyboard.

There are a lot of Stack Overflow posts about the new xcode 6 storyboard, if you need information on this.
You can also check out the WWDC videos on [Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216) and [What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#411) for some background.